# Replacing the value of a substring but one

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to replace all the occurrences of a sub-string with another string. But I do not want to replace the occurrence of a sub-string in a particular sub-string within the main string.

**Example**

```
string main = "The value for v and p are not v and p"
string replacestring= "v";
main = main.Replace(replacestring,12);
```

**Result**

```
main = The 12alue for 12 and p are not 12 and p
```

**Expected Result**

```
main =The value for 12 and p are not v and p.
```

So basically I am not trying to skip the first occurrence of the substring but the whole sub-string `value`. I do not want it to be replaced for any value of `replacestring`. I have tried to find the index of the first occurrence of the sub-string `value` and skipping the next 4 characters and then replacing. But it isn't efficient enough for me as can have more than one occurrence of `value`.

Comment: You can use a regex replacement: `Regex.Replace(str, @"\bv\b", "12")`

Comment: Why isn't it replacing the third occurrence of "v"?

Comment: @stribizhev: in that case will `v1` be replaced to `121`?

Comment: @juharr: I do not want it to be replaced. I only want the first occurrence other than in `value` to be repalced. But if the third occurence is replaced it isnt a problem,

Comment: `Regex.Replace(str, @"^((?:(?!\bv\b).)*)\bv\b", "${1}12")`

Comment: @Vini No that regular expression expects word boundaries on both sides of the "v".  But why wouldn't you be replacing "v1" in that case?  Or are you saying you don't want it to replace the "v" in "v1"?

Comment: Other than string.Replace, you could probably see if string.Insert method can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace *the first* `v` as a whole word, use

```
var rx1 = new Regex(@"\bv\b");
var t = rx1.Replace("The value for v and p are not v and p", "12", 1);
```

[image]

See [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The last `1` argument is *`count`* (*the maximum number of times the replacement can occur.*)

The regex `\bv\b` matches any `v` that is enclosed with non-word characters (non-letters, non-digits, and non-`_`s).

Whenever you are building a regex dynamically, make sure you

- use verbatim string literals so as to use only single backslash to escape regex metacharacters
- `Regex.Escape` method should be used when you need to match some value *literally*.

Thus, use

```
var s = "v";
var rx1 = new Regex(@"\b" + Regex.Escape(s) + @"\b");
// or
// var rx1 = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(s)));
var t = rx1.Replace("The value for v and p are not v and p", "12", 1);
```

Comment: I have used your method `string s1 = "\b" + s + "\b";
                                var rx1 = new Regex(s1);
                                
                                formula = rx1.Replace(formula, rep,1);` but it doesnt replace. I have tried by adding both `@` and without it. where s is the string to be replaced and rep is the value that should be inserted in place s.

Comment: No, `\b` is a backspace character. Use verbatim string literals and the `Regex.Escape` with dynamic regexps: `string s1 = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(s) + @"\b";`. See my answer update.

Comment: thanks for the new edit. It works. But i have tocheck the normal cases as well.. And do you mind explaining why it works?

Comment: I think it works in all cases that I have checked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Excuse me, could you please precise what exactly I should explain in a greater detail? The word boundary `\b`? You can read about them at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). As I wrote, `\bv\b` will be matched when `v` is preceded and followed by spaces, punctuation, all non-digits, non-letters and non-underscores.

Comment: So in that case if `Va` is the string to be replaced will it replace `Value` as well ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. i could check for all possible combinations. i cant do so in my project as the values are taken from the database.